# How can I tell if there are two equal numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

How can I tell if there are two equal numbers in an array-

For example

> array [4] = {2,3,7,2}

If I have two numbers in an array equal then true if not then false.
How I implement this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You can sort the array and compare values next to each other. Alternative is to compare the first element to the rest, then the second to the rest, and so on.

Comment: I thought about checking out all the numbers how often they appear, and by this test

Answer (score 2):

**O(n)** method:

1. Create a hash table.
2. Scan the array, use the hash table to count the frequency of each element.
3. Scan the hash table. If one with frequency>1, then true, false otherwise.

---

**O(nlog n)** method:

1. Sort the array in **O(nlog n)**.
2. Scan the array from the start to end. Keep two indexes: previous and current. Check current is equal to previous or not. - **O(n)**

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int array[4] = {2, 3, 7, 2};
    bool check = false;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 4; j++){
            if (j != i && array[j] == array[i])
                check = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", check);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your array is dense, that is not a lot of numbers are missing, you can even do this in *O(n)* with memory requirements: *O(max-min)* (this is why your array should not be sparse).

Simply index the array, by

1. Run through the entire array (`a`) and compute the minimum and the maximum -- *Theta(n)*
2. Create a new array (`buffer`) of size maximum - minimum + 1 and initialise it to `0` -- *Theta(maximum - minimum)*
3. Run through `a` again and for each `a[i]` increment `buffer[a[i]-minimum]` by one. If in any of these steps, you encounter a value of `buffer[a[i]-minimum]` that was already incremented, you return that you found a double entry -- *O(n)*
4. If you managed to complete the last step without returning, return that there is none -- *O(1)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    int i,j;
    unsigned int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
      for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
      {
        if(a[i]==a[j])
        printf("%d", arr[i]);  
      }
    }
```

By this way you get all numbers those are repeating.

Comment: check this for more information. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-two-repeating-elements-in-a-given-array/